# Using Twitter4j, i gather a bunch of tweets and then use contains() to find words in them, but contains() is not working

Tags: java, twitter4j

So I gather tweets from twitter using Twitter4j, add each one to a list named statuses, and then check each statuses text for the word "the" using an if statement and contains. If true, it adds one to a counter and then at the end, displays the counter, but the counter always says 0 even if the was in the tweet. code is as follows:

```
for (Status status : statuses) {

            String fullTweet = ((follower.getScreenName() + " - " + status.getCreatedAt() + " - " + status.getText()).replaceAll("\\n", "").replaceAll("\\r", ""));

            System.out.println(fullTweet);

            if (fullTweet.toLowerCase().contains("the")) {

                the = the++;

            }

}
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `contains`. Please consider what `the = the++` does.

Comment: When you think that an if statement is not executing correctly, the next step is to add a logging or print statement to see what branch is taken or not taken. Or use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Write your increment as `the += 1` instead of `the = the++`, or simply `the++`.
You're assigning the value before the increment, since having ++ after the variable is a post increment.